# I am new to coding and watching a tutorial. These lines work in the tutorial, but Eclipse keeps telling me there is an error

Tags: java

```
public class LearnJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name = "Susan";
        System.out.println(name.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: D:\java\JavaTutorial\bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: LearnJava.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Comment: You need to declare the variable `name`

Comment: It should be `String name = "Susan";`

Answer (score -1):

```
public class LearnJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Susan";
        System.out.println(name.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: While change is necessary, it doesn't address problem that the OP is asking about.  (Hint: read the entire question, not just the code.)

Comment: Please describe your solution, not just drop the code

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).